# Able to vote after reaching daily limit

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, rate-limiting

I burnt through my 30+x votes very quickly today, leading to the notice (in blue upon reaching the limit, in red upon trying to vote thereafter):

> You've reached your daily vote limit; vote again in 11 hours.

But then I was cruising over some answers, and I was able to cast a vote on an answer. (In case it helps, I know which answer it is, but I won't disclose it immediately.)

Again, the notice was displayed (this time with "vote again in 1 hour") in blue, and the vote was counted; it also appears in my profile (the number of votes cast has gone up by one). After this one successful vote, I got the red notice again, and my votes don't get counted.

Is there any explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: In addition, you have 10 extra votes for questions only that do not count towards the 30 (part of [Optimizing for pearls, not sand](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/))

Comment: @mixedmath Thanks, I know that; that's why I wrote 30+x.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is by design. Votes on deleted posts do not count toward your daily limit. If you hit the limit after voting on $m$ posts, and $n$ of these posts get deleted for any reason before the end of the UTC day, you will be able to cast $m+n$ votes that day. See [How does someone get to cast more than 40 votes in a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124172/224469)

You may be able to observe the difference between the number of votes listed on your [votes tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/43351/lord-farin?tab=votes) (which do not include votes on deleted posts, at least for $<10$K users), and the number ($36$) reported elsewhere in your profile.

Comment: Thanks for doing a better job searching MSO than I did myself.

Comment: @Lord_Farin  Hmmm...user79365 seems to be really informed of MSE, or SE sites in general, and he made a lot of community wiki answer to some old un-answered questions...really a nice guy...